# Cannot Modify the TextView in a NavigationView

Tags: java, android, navigationview

I'm trying to update the name and the e-mail in a NavigationView based on the user that is currently logged in the app in Firebase. This is my code (I used the template from Android Studio for NavigationView):

```
public class MainApp2 extends AppCompatActivity{

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainApp2Binding binding;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    FirebaseUser user;
    String email, name;
    TextView mail, nam;

    //View header= naviView.getHeaderView(0);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View naviView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.nav_header_main_app2, null);
        /*NavigationView navigView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigView.addHeaderView(naviView);*/

        fAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user= fAuth.getCurrentUser();

        binding = ActivityMainApp2Binding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMainApp2.toolbar);
       /* binding.appBarMainApp2.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });*/
        DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main_app2);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);


        mail=(TextView)naviView.findViewById(R.id.email_nav);
        nam=drawer.findViewById(R.id.name_nav);
        System.out.println("1."+user.getEmail());
        System.out.println("2."+user.getDisplayName());

        if(user!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(email=user.getEmail());
            email=user.getEmail();
            //name=user.getDisplayName().toString().trim();
            mail.setText(email);
            //nam.setText(name);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_app2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main_app2);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

I used to get null pointer error, but after adding the line

```
View naviView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.nav_header_main_app2, null);
```

I don't get the error, but the text is not changing either. I also tried with

```
/*NavigationView navigView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigView.addHeaderView(naviView);*/
```

but I got an error on (this). I'm new on Android Studio and I don't know how to solve this problem without the errors and with the text actually changing.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the error. I had to initialize the NavigationView after the binding, so after these two lines

```
DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
```

I put my code and it worked without errors.